# Restore RAID 0 with one member disk having been written to

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, storage, raid-0

Due to a bad overclock I had to reset my CMOS. This caused my RAID 0 to show up as "failed". One disk was detected as member the other detected as "Non raid disk".
I have no reason to believe that the drive failed.

My mistake was going into Windows and opening the parition managment. It asked me to initialize the "Non raid disk" with a GPT and I clicked yes. I didn't think, read it right and clicked too fast...

So to restore the RAIS I then deleted to and recreated the array with identical settings. Boot into windows and use Teskdisk to recover the Windows partition.

Testdisk didn't find any parition, which is probably because I wrote the GPT to the second disk.

I know the data is still there, the disks are fine and the new/old RAID is working. Except it's now misaligned?

Any tips on how to fix this? I know how the original parition was setup, in case that helps.

Edit:
My disk are working fine. This is not a duplicate of [RAID 0 disk failure, how to recover the RAID?](https://superuser.com/questions/34255/raid-0-disk-failure-how-to-recover-the-raid)

All I need is a way to "undo" the GPT write to fix the parition.

Edit2:

I finally got the testdisk results back after 12h:

```
Disk /dev/sdd - 4000 GB / 3726 GiB - CHS 486401 255 63
The harddisk (4000 GB / 3726 GiB) seems too small! (< 8001 GB / 7451 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection...

The following partition can't be recovered:
Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors

  MS Data               7814045695 15627827198 7813781504
```

It detected two partitions, both 4TB. 
My drives are both 2TB. So it sees two partitions where there used to be only one. This is consistent with my assumtion that Windows created a second GPT on the second disk. I can enter the second partition so see all my files, except copying fails. Entering the first partion fails.

This is the result of the testdisk analysis:

```
Disk /dev/sdd - 4000 GB / 3726 GiB - CHS 486401 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 D MS Data                     2048 4294965247 4294963200
>D MS Data                   264192 7814045695 7813781504 [Raid]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RAID 0 disk failure, how to recover the RAID?](https://superuser.com/questions/34255/raid-0-disk-failure-how-to-recover-the-raid)